# Select box behaviour in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

```
<title>Sample</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<select onchange="alert('hi')">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Option1</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option1</option>
</select>

<script>
    
    
    $('select').bind('change',function(){
    var a ="true";
    })



</script>
```

In Firefox alert is getting called only once.

In IE7/8 alert is coming twice. Just wondering why in IE alert is coming twice?

Comment: What do you mean by "only once" ? Only once on the page, or only once on each change?

Comment: Is the jQuery code relevant to the question? Is the result different without it?

Comment: @Pekka, @Kobi - The jQuery event handler **with** the inline `onchange` is the issue here, only in IE.

Answer (score 4):

It's not you, it's a jQuery bug with IE, filed in the bug tracker [here](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6310), [here](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6593) and [here](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/7000)....unfortunately it looks like it'll be jQuery 1.5 before they make a change fixing this.

Currently (only in IE) the DOM 0 event handler is triggered (your inline `onchange`) then the jQuery handler...then something about that execution causes the DOM 0 handler to fire *again*.